# Cannot install react-app because of a node version problem but I do have the last version installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

All is in the title: I am trying to create a react-app following this tutorial: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

But it fails immediately saying the following:

```
[user@localhost workspace]$ create-react-app projectname
Creating a new React app in projectpath/projectname.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...
yarn add v1.6.0
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > strip-comments > babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread > babel-runtime > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
warning react-scripts > jest > jest-cli > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error eslint@6.7.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^8.10.0 || ^10.13.0 || >=11.10.1".
error Found incompatible module
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd projectpath/projectname has failed.
```

From "The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version" I deduce that my node is not up to date. However:

`sudo n stable` gives me:
installed : v12.13.1 to /usr/local/bin/node
active : v10.16.3 at /bin/node

`nvm use stable` gives me:
Now using node v10.0.0 (npm v6.13.4)

`node -v` gives me:
v10.0.0

Anyone has an idea to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: What does `node -v` give?

Comment: eslint@6.7.2 can be used with node 10.13.0, or greater than 11.10.1 version. Have you tried to install 10.13.0 or a greater version?

Comment: try to use yarn with `--ignore-engines` switch.

Comment: @JoseVasquez actually I realized I was using `sudo n stable` but it does not give me the last version for node. I just used `sudo n latest` which gives me : `   installed : v13.3.0 to /usr/local/bin/node
active : v10.16.3 at /bin/node
` Do you know how I can make the "installed" version the "active" one?

Comment: @Zydnar I just tried your solution, unfortunately the issue stays :/ Thank you for the suggestion though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I finally found how to use the version I want thanks to the following resources 
https://alligator.io/nodejs/node-version-manager/

I don't know why I was always stuck with the version 10.0.0. I even uninstalled and reinstalled npm and node specifying I wanted the last version of node and it reinstalled me the 10.0.0 version...

The link above provide the following **magic** command:

`nvm install 12`

It downloads **AND** setup the version 12 of node as **ACTIVE**:

"Upon running each command, nvm will download the version of Node.js from the official website and install it. Once installed, it will also set the version you just installed as the active version."

Answer (score 0):

I found an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7503) on that topic on GitHub.

The last comment says that you have to run all these commands:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

and then you should be fine

Comment: Unfortunately it does not change anything. Again it is telling me ``` installed : v12.13.1 to /usr/local/bin/node
      active : v10.16.3 at /bin/node
 ```

Comment: " [2/4] Fetching packages...
error eslint@6.7.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^8.10.0 || ^10.13.0 || >=11.10.1".
error Found incompatible module
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
 "